# combine plotly and folium

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, folium

Using python I am trying to build a map with markers using Folium. This is working fine, however now I've started to try and add plot.ly graphs into the map which doesn't work well. Is it impossible to have javascript inside leaflets (Folium) popups?

The js code which is in the html file is shown below:

```
var marker_7ecf53df703f455c9b8e9342784a4fde = L.marker([-30.0,31.25], {
            icon: new L.Icon.Default()
        }
    ).addTo(map_698b07e412264d16ab4a7628d18d6a7a);


var popup_d63d578364d04568bda1b68bc0a870d7 = L.popup({maxWidth: '300'});

var html_deaec1fcc80d483faff605dcfa6691ff = $('<div id="html_deaec1fcc80d483faff605dcfa6691ff" style="width: 100.0%; height: 100.0%;"><div id="5be3c360-6f61-47fc-af22-c43d8a2c16ed" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" class="plotly-graph-div"></div><script type="text/javascript">window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};window.PLOTLYENV.BASE_URL="https://plot.ly";Plotly.newPlot("5be3c360-6f61-47fc-af22-c43d8a2c16ed", [{"marker": {"color": "rgb(106,81,163)"}, "r": [77.5, 72.5, 70.0, 45.0, 22.5, 42.5, 40.0, 62.5], "type": "area", "name": "11-14 m/s", "t": [0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315]}], {"radialaxis": {"ticksuffix": "%"}, "title": "Wind Speed Distribution in Laurel, NE", "font": {"size": 16}, "orientation": 270, "legend": {"font": {"size": 16}}}, {"linkText": "Export to plot.ly", "showLink": true})</script></div>')[0];

popup_d63d578364d04568bda1b68bc0a870d7.setContent(html_deaec1fcc80d483faff605dcfa6691ff);

marker_7ecf53df703f455c9b8e9342784a4fde.bindPopup(popup_d63d578364d04568bda1b68bc0a870d7);
```

I include the popups like such:

```
for rowNum, rowValues in data.iterrows():
    popup = folium.Html(polarHtml, script=True) # polarHtml is the html
    folium.Marker([rowValues['latitude'], rowValues['longitude']], popup=folium.Popup(popup)).add_to(map_osm)
```

The map works fine if I just use simple HTML inside the popups. Does anybody know where this goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I did "solve" it in the end. Although I am not a big fan of IFrames I ended up combining folium.HTML and folium.IFrame like so:

```
folium.Popup(folium.Html('aa<br>'+folium.IFrame(polarHtml, width='410px', height='410px').render(), script=True), max_width=2650)
```